# Bucle al descargar archivo KML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

estoy intentando descargar un archivo kml después de una consulta, el detalle es que si descarga el archivo bien pero después de la descarga se queda en bucle con un mensaje de "por favor espere" y en herramientas de desarrollador me arroja un error 403, en base a mi código que mostraré a continuación que esta saliendo mal? intente redireccionar a otra parte pero no funciona se queda con el mismo mensaje, les agradecería su ayuda

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<FileContentResult> DownloadKML(DateTime Fecha)
{
    List<Recorrido> datosCamiones = new List<Recorrido>();

    // Tu código actual...

    datosCamiones = await db.Recorridos
        .Where(x => x.Fecha == Fecha )
        .OrderBy(x => x.Fecha)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Hora)
        .ToListAsync();

    string contenidoKML = await ObtenerArchivoKMLAsync(datosCamiones, Fecha);

    // Resto del código...

    return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contenidoKML), "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml", Fecha.ToString() + ".kml");


}

private async Task<string> ObtenerArchivoKMLAsync(List<Recorrido> datosCamiones, DateTime fecha)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n");
    sb.Append("<kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\">\n");
    sb.Append("<Document>\n");

    // Resto del código...

    // Obtener nombres únicos de camiones
    var nombresCamionesUnicos = datosCamiones.Select(camion => camion.IMEI).Distinct().ToArray();

    // Iterar sobre los nombres de camiones únicos
    foreach (var nombreCamion in nombresCamionesUnicos)
    {
        sb.Append("<Placemark>\n");
        sb.Append($"  <name>{nombreCamion}</name>\n");
        sb.Append("  <visibility>0</visibility>\n");
        sb.Append("  <styleUrl>#lineStyleColor</styleUrl>\n");
        sb.Append("  <LineString>\n");
        sb.Append("    <coordinates>\n");

        // Obtener las coordenadas para el camión actual
        var coordenadasCamion = await Task.Run(() => datosCamiones // datosCamiones 
            .Where(camion => camion.IE == nombreCamion
            .Select(coordenada => $"{coordenada.Lon.ToString("F4")},{coordenada.Lat.ToString("F4")},0 ")
            .ToArray());

        // Unir las coordenadas en una cadena sin espacios adicionales
        string coordenadasString = string.Join(",", coordenadasCamion);

        sb.Append($"      {coordenadasString}\n");

        sb.Append("    </coordinates>\n");
        sb.Append("  </LineString>\n");
        sb.Append("</Placemark>\n");
    }

    // Resto del código...

    return sb.ToString();
}
```